# How to convert lower case character into upper case after each special character present in the String?

Tags: java, string

Need to change character from lower case into upper case after each special character present in the string.

i tried using  indexOf("_") +1 and get the posstion in the string and tried but no luck

If my input string values is =  "java_compiler_code_example"

then i am expecting  =  java_Compiler_Code_Example

After each special character "_" i wanted to change that character from lower case into upper case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will take your sample String split it on the `separtar`, go through and uppercase each word after the first the combined them back and return it.

```
public String cammelCase(String sampleString, String separator) {
  String[] split = sampleString.split(separator);

  if (split.length < 2) return sampleString;

  for (int i =  1; i < split.length; i++) {
   split[i] = split[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + split[i].substring(1);
  }

  String retStr = "";
  for (int i =0; i < split.length; i++) {
    resStr += split[i];
    if (i != split.length - 1) {
      retStr += separator;
     }
  }
 return retStr;
}
```